# In a find command, what does "{} +" at the end mean?

Tags: shell, find

```
find -L / -samefile /path/to/file -exec ls -ld {} +
```

What does the `{} +` mean?

Example from [CommandLineFu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8354/find-all-the-links-to-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's part of the `-exec` option to `find`; `{}` expands to the current file name, and `+` (nonportably; should be `\;` or `';'` or similar) indicates the end of the command arguments.

Comment: Actually, I found out recently that the `+` is standard in [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) from POSIX 2008.  You may still be right about 'not all that portable' since not all systems support it, but it is a standard notation.

Comment: @Jonathan: On Solaris you need to use the POSIX/XPG version of `find` for it to work.

Comment: In fact, it is available in SUSv3 (POSIX 2004) as well, see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html).

Comment: Also the answer is wrong due to `{}` expanding to a lot more than just the *current* file name.

Answer (score 7):

That's part of the syntax of the `find` command.  When giving `find` a subcommand to execute on each match, a `{}` must be inserted into the argument list to indicate where `find` should place the pathname of the current file.  The subcommand is terminated by either a semicolon (quoted to avoid parsing by the shell) or by a plus sign, the latter indicating that `find` should replace the `{}` with as many pathnames at once as possible, in contrast to just one at a time for `;`.

Comment: thanks for stating the difference between `+` and `;`